# Terminology and intuition about valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, algebraic-number-theory

When I first heard the term "valuation", I imagined something like evaluating polynomials in $k[X]$ or functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$ at some fixed point $a$. Valuations in a Dedekind ring $R$ (almost?) correspond bijectively to prime ideals, and I've heard that in modern number theory people think of elements in $R$ as functions on the spectrum $\text{Spec}(R)$, whose points are the prime ideals, so that strengthened by previous belief. However I just realized that the map $e:k[X]\rightarrow k,f(x)\mapsto f(a)$ is far from being a valuation. Here are my questions.

1. So why do we call them "valuations"? Because of the Dedekind ring example? But very few maps $\text{Spec}(R)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ come from some element in $R$.
2. Is there any connection between valuations and the map $f(x)\mapsto f(a)$?
3. Another important example of valuation is the map that sends $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_kx^k$ (where $a_k\neq 0$) to $k$. Is it still possible to think of this as "valuating a map at some point"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact a connection between valuations and evaluation maps, in that you can sometimes think of valuations as measuring the "order of vanishing" of a function at a specific point.  For instance, your last example that sends a polynomial $f(x)$ to the exponent on the lowest power of $x$ appearing in it can be thought of as the "order of vanishing" of $f$ at $0$.  This is related to evaluation at $0$ in that the order of vanishing is positive iff $f(0)=0$, and more generally the order of vanishing measures "how strongly" $f(0)$ is $0$.  Similarly, any nonzero prime ideal $p$ in a Dedekind domain $R$ corresponds to a valuation, and that valuation can be thought of as measuring the "order of vanishing" at $p$ when you think of elements of $R$ as functions on $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

From an etymological perspective, though, this connection is entirely coincidental: the term "valuation" is not used because it is similar to "evaluation".  There is really not any particular reason the word "valuation" is used instead of any other and you should not try to read any special meaning into the word.  The way I understand the motivation behind it is that you are sort of assigning a "value" to elements in the sense of somehow measuring their "size" or "how much" of something they have (e.g., how many factors of $p$ they have, for the $p$-adic valuation).  Like much of mathematical terminology, though, the choice of specific word is rather arbitrary.  The notion of a "valuation" is not modeled on evaluation maps and you should not try to understand it as a generalization of evaluation maps.

Comment: That long parenthetical 3rd paragraph really should be emphasized.  Consider putting it first.  Thinking of valuations as an order-of-vanishing (for polynomials) or order-of divisibility (for integers) is the most basic intuition.  Saying "it's just a word" is not as helpful by comparison.

Comment: Under another convention, valuation becomes order-of-infinity, is that correct? Then can I say this valuation is "evaluating $f$ at infinity"?

Comment: @xXF: If you negate the sign of an "order of vanishing" valuation then it becomes something you could think of as measuring the "order of infinity" or "order of pole" at a point.  Be careful, though--it sounds like you are confusing "order of infinity" (i.e., "how strongly" is infinity the *output* of the function at a given point) with "evaluating at infinity" (which would be taking infinity as the *input* of the function instead).  These are totally different things.

Comment: Aren't they somewhat related? Denote by $v$ the valuation on $\mathbb{R}[x]$. $v(f)=v(g)$ iff they have the same highest exponent, iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and is nonzero. Actually I was thinking of literally plugging in infinity, and perhaps relate this to nonstandard analysis. Edit: Ah but this only works for $k=\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @xXF: That is about the *highest* exponent, though, not the *lowest* exponent which is the valuation related to evaluation at $0$.  There is indeed a valuation like that which can be thought of as the "order of vanishing at infinity", but this is separate from how negating an "order of vanishing" function gives you an "order of infinity" function.